# Magento 2 - How to add external css/script to head?

Tags: magento2, head

I try to add external css/javascript to the head. I added this to my theme under **Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
              crossorigin="anonymous"
              src_type="url"
              type="text/css"
        >

        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                src_type="url"
        >
        </script>
    </head>
</page>
```

But it does not load the files and they are not showing in the sourcecode.

I also removed the attributes `integrity` and `crossorigin` but it still fails. I executed `grunt clean` to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      src_type="url"
      type="text/css"
>
```

to:

```
<css src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      src_type="url"
>
```

**Note**: I had to change `link` to `css` and `href` to `src`